# Remove lines on sides on navbar item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap. When I have a white background, there is no issue and the navbar item looks as follows which is fine:

[image: white]

But when I have a blue background, I get 2 lines on the sides as follows. Is there any way to remove it? I tried border: 0 and makes no difference.

[image: blue]

```
<!-- HTML Code -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
</ul>

/*CSS Code overriding bootstrap*/
.navbar-nav{
    border:0;
}
```

Comment: replicate your error here http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/yeEMPV

Comment: Add an ID attribute to your unordered list and then apply the styles using the ID selector.

Comment: @HTMLNoob actually that is not exactly ideal. But close. Add a "class" and apply styles to that or use specificity by using a parent class as a hook class and path it to the LI and then apply your styles there. IDs should never be used with CSS. They are unique, which means you can't reuse it in the same page, and they do not cascade like classes do

Comment: @LOTUSMS http://codepen.io/angersleek/pen/jWKBKM?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your CODEPEN, your border issue is in the `a` tag, not the `li` tag.

Add this to your CSS:

```
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li:last-child > a {
     border: none;
}
```

See the corrected [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/MKXpBo?editors=1100)

Answer (score 1):

css:

```
a {
    border:none !important;
}
```

(!important takes priority above everything else)